# Delete user meta ( delete_user_meta ) by key without user id

Tags: user-meta

I am new at WordPress. I am not sure is it possible or not that if I want to delete user metadata by passing the only key.
for example:

```
delete_user_meta( $key );
```

But looks like required a user id. Is there any other way to work like this?

Comment: So you want to delete it from all users?

Comment: yes. just by matching the key.

Comment: You probably want to write a SQL query to do that then. Or search for users by your meta key and then iterate over them deleting the property.

Comment: @Rup, yes. I think that's the only way for now.